# Arranging the stacks in a stacked bargraph according to the value of one variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am trying to write a function that outputs a stacked bar graph at the end, where the stacked bar graph has its' bars ordered going from the greatest percentage to the smallest percentage of one specific variable. I have not been able to find a general way to do this and my ultimate goal is to have this process done in a way where it requires the least amount of human input.

My data looks like this

```
 Swimming_style     Comfort_level_label    Comfort_level_scale    n     Total_n       Percentage 
 Front Crawl        Excellent              3                     7       10          70                     
 Front Crawl        Good                   2                     3       10          30
 Backstroke         Excellent              3                     4       10          40
 Backstroke         Good                   2                     4       10          40
 Backstroke         Fair                   1                     1       10          10
 Backstroke         Poor                   0                     1       10          10
 Brest stroke       Excellent              3                     6       10          60
 Brest stroke       Fair                   1                     4       10          40
 Butterfly          Good                   2                     7       10          70
 Butterfly          Fair                   1                     1       10          10
 Butterfly          Poor                   0                     2       10          20
```

So far, this is my code:

```
 data <- arrange(data, Comfort_level_label, (Percentage))
 data$Swimming_style <- factor(data$Swimming_style, levels = unique(data$Swimming_style))



 ggplot(data, aes( x = Swimming_style, y = n, fill = Comfort_level_label)) + 
      geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") + 
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+
     coord_flip()
```

Which outputs this:

[image]

But what I need the graph to do is sort by the Excellent rating from most Excellent on top to least or no Excellent on the bottom, and I'm having trouble doing exactly that.

Comment: Almost every question that asks *"... ggplot2 ... order ..."* is answered with `factor`s.  You are creating the `factor` but you're giving it an arbitrary order (with the `levels=` argument). Change that to be the order you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a little ambiguous, but the important thing when prioritizing is to ensure you always have exactly one of each of the factors.

```r
library(dplyr)
SS <- dat %>%
  arrange(-Comfort_level_scale, -n) %>%
  group_by(Swimming_style) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Comfort_level_scale, n) %>%
  pull(Swimming_style)

library(ggplot2)
dat %>%
  mutate(Swimming_style = factor(Swimming_style, levels = SS)) %>%
  ggplot(aes( x = Swimming_style, y = n, fill = Comfort_level_label)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: ggplot2 ordered facets]

BTW: should `Brest stroke` be `Breast stroke`?

---

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
 Swimming_style     Comfort_level_label    Comfort_level_scale    n     Total_n       Percentage 
 Front_Crawl        Excellent              3                     7       10          70                     
 Front_Crawl        Good                   2                     3       10          30
 Backstroke         Excellent              3                     4       10          40
 Backstroke         Good                   2                     4       10          40
 Backstroke         Fair                   1                     1       10          10
 Backstroke         Poor                   0                     1       10          10
 Brest_stroke       Excellent              3                     6       10          60
 Brest_stroke       Fair                   1                     4       10          40
 Butterfly          Good                   2                     7       10          70
 Butterfly          Fair                   1                     1       10          10
 Butterfly          Poor                   0                     2       10          20") %>%
  mutate(Swimming_style = gsub("_", " ", Swimming_style))
```

Comment: Yes, it should be breast stroke.
If I'm reading your code correctly, it's arranging based on Swimming_style. If I were to set factor levels as a list of Excellent,Good,Fair, and Poor and then use that list to determine the order of stacked bar graphs, what would I have to do? Play with the mutate string?

Comment: The `factor` levels should go on style, not on `Comfort_level_label`. You already have `Comfort_level_scale`, so your prioritization order is already included. Does this plot look as intuitively-ordered as you would expect?

Comment: The plot looks perfect. Thank you for the help. I just had to go over a few things to make sure I understood them.